# Gst Pipeline not running when using interleave element with two sinks

Tags: python, gstreamer

I'm having a problem with the usage of the interleave element in a gstreamer pipeline.

I'm reading audio from an Input (autoaudiosrc) into a tee so I can write it to disk and get the audio levels in realtime (gonna feed a hardware vu meter with it, in the attached snippet it just prints the level to stdout). I wanna be able to use any 1 or 2 channels and write them to a separate file so I'm able to split 6 input channels into 5 files (1 stereo, 4 mono).
Now writing everything to one file worked fine, then I've added an deinterleave element to split everything into mono files which also worked fine, but combining two channels into one stereo channels breaks the whole pipeline.

```
def new_recorder_bin(path, sinks=1):
    bin = Gst.Bin()
    interleave = Gst.ElementFactory.make('interleave', None)
    queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue', None)
    encoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make('wavenc', None)
    output = Gst.ElementFactory.make('filesink', None)
    output.set_property('location', path)
    bin.add(interleave)
    bin.add(queue)
    bin.add(encoder)
    bin.add(output)
    interleave.link(queue)
    queue.link(encoder)
    encoder.link(output)
    if sinks == 1:
        interleave.set_property('channel_positions', [GstAudio.AudioChannelPosition.MONO])
        sink = interleave.get_request_pad('sink_0')
        ghostpad = Gst.GhostPad.new('sink_0', sink)
        bin.add_pad(ghostpad)
    elif sinks == 2:
        interleave.set_property('channel_positions', [
            GstAudio.AudioChannelPosition.FRONT_LEFT,
            GstAudio.AudioChannelPosition.FRONT_RIGHT
        ])
        sink0 = interleave.get_request_pad('sink_0')
        ghostpad0 = Gst.GhostPad.new('sink_0', sink0)
        sink1 = interleave.get_request_pad('sink_1')
        ghostpad1 = Gst.GhostPad.new('sink_1', sink1)
        bin.add_pad(ghostpad0)
        bin.add_pad(ghostpad1)
    return bin
```

This is the code which creates a new bin to write one or two channels to disk. When I attach to only one sink pad (and set sinks to 1) everything still works fine, but when I attach two sink pads (and set sinks to 2) the file gets created but the pipe seems to be stuck. Neither the level gets printed out nor data is written to the file.

I've attached the complete file in a gist, this is prototyping code but before I refactor this I want everything to work as it should.

https://gist.github.com/maxjoehnk/16785499db6e864bf120cf85a81b1ecf

Comment: Not sure how exactly your complete pipeline looks like. But since all of your audio comes from the one thread (same audio source). I would expect the interleave element to block itself. Try adding queue elements before the interleave sink pads.

Comment: Right now I have a tee which"splits" the signal into two queue's, one for the level element and one for the deinterleave element. The source code for the complete pipeline can be found in the gist I've linked. Do I really need to add a queue per pad or just per element? Because I have a queue right behind the interleave element, I'm not quite sure how I would add it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the comment by [Florian Zwoch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5215131/florian-zwoch) was the clue. I've added a queue per channel and now everything works fine. So my new_recorder_bin function now looks like this:

```
def new_recorder_bin(path, sinks=1):
    bin = Gst.Bin()
    interleave = Gst.ElementFactory.make('interleave', None)
    encoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make('wavenc', None)
    output = Gst.ElementFactory.make('filesink', None)
    output.set_property('location', path)
    bin.add(interleave)
    bin.add(encoder)
    bin.add(output)
    interleave.link(encoder)
    encoder.link(output)
    if sinks == 1:
        queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue', None)
        bin.add(queue)
        interleave.set_property('channel_positions', [GstAudio.AudioChannelPosition.MONO])
        sink = interleave.get_request_pad('sink_0')
        queueSink = queue.get_static_pad('sink')
        queueSrc = queue.get_static_pad('src')
        queueSrc.link(sink)
        ghostpad = Gst.GhostPad.new('sink_0', queueSink)
        bin.add_pad(ghostpad)
    elif sinks == 2:
        queue0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue', 'Queue L')
        queue1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue', 'Queue R')
        bin.add(queue0)
        bin.add(queue1)
        interleave.set_property('channel_positions', [
            GstAudio.AudioChannelPosition.FRONT_LEFT,
            GstAudio.AudioChannelPosition.FRONT_RIGHT
        ])
        sink0 = interleave.get_request_pad('sink_0')
        queueSink0 = queue0.get_static_pad('sink')
        queueSrc0 = queue0.get_static_pad('src')
        queueSrc0.link(sink0)
        ghostpad0 = Gst.GhostPad.new('sink_0', queueSink0)
        sink1 = interleave.get_request_pad('sink_1')
        queueSink1 = queue1.get_static_pad('sink')
        queueSrc1 = queue1.get_static_pad('src')
        queueSrc1.link(sink1)
        ghostpad1 = Gst.GhostPad.new('sink_1', queueSink1)
        bin.add_pad(ghostpad0)
        bin.add_pad(ghostpad1)
    return bin
```

This isn't particularly clean but it seems to work fine so for now I will stick with it.